# How to synchronize two Subversion repositories?

Tags: svn, version-control, synchronization

My company has a subsidiary with a slow Internet connection. Our developers there suffer to interact with our central [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29) server. Is it possible to configure a slave/mirror  for them? They would interact locally with the server and all the commits would be automatically synchronized to the master server.

This should work as transparently as possible for the developers. Usability is a must.

Please, no suggestions to change our version control system.

Comment: I am skeptical how proxying may improve matters. It's possible a commit takes less time for the user's POV, but the data still has to be transmitted to the master, and this still takes the same amount of network bandwidth. Thus updating the master is just as slow, even if it appears faster for the user. Due to this asynchronous behaviour the master may start lagging behind.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Subversion 1.5 introduced proxy support when you're using http to host your repository. Developers can checkout their working copies from the slave. Then all read-only operations (diff, log, update etc) will use the slave. When committing, the slave transparently passes all write operation to the master.

Comment: BTW, I'm in another job and not even using Subversion anymore. I've successfully implemented the proxy solution. Argh, it isn't easy to configure Apache and Subversion in Windows. The greatest problem was when a failure happened during the sync. The solution was to have a boot time script to cleanup. Now a non-technical person can just reboot the machine and everything works again.

Comment: There were/are bugs in which can cause svn proxying to not work (well). It's the reason why I didn't get it to work yet with my setup. See for example  http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3275
http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3445 the latter is still open.

Answer (score 49):

It is possible but not necessarily simple: the problem you are trying to solve is dangerously close to setting up a distributed development environment which is not exactly what SVN is designed for.

**The SVN-mirror way**

You can use `svn mirror` as explained in the SVN book documentation to create a *read-only* mirror of your master repository. Your developers each interact with the mirror closest to them. However users of the slave repository will have to use

svn switch --relocate master_url

before they can commit and they will have to remember to relocate back on the slave once they are done. This could be automated using a wrapper script around the repository modifying commands on SVN if you use the command line client. Keep in mind that the relocate operation while fast adds a bit of overhead. (And be careful to duplicate the repository uuid - see [the SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication).)

[Edit - Checking the [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) documentation it seems that you can have TortoiseSVN [execute hook scripts client side](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks). You may be able to create a pre/post commit script at this point. Either that or try to see if you can use the [TortoiseSVN automation interface](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) to do it].

**The SVK way**

[svk](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage) is a set of Perl scripts which emulate a distributed mirroring service over SVN. You can set it up so that the local branch (the mirror) is shared by multiple developers. Then basic usage for the developers will be completely transparent. You will have to use the svk client for cherry picking, merging and starmerging. It is doable if you can get your head around the distributed concepts.

**The git-svn way**

While I never used that myself, you could also have distant developers use git locally and use the [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) gateway for synchronization.

**Final words**

It all depends on your development environment and the level of integration you require. Depending on your IDE (and if you can change [SCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Management)) you might want to have a look at other fully distributed SCMs (think [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial)/[Bazaar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar_%28software%29)/[Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29)/...) which support distributed development out of the box.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a a TortoiseSVN client script to automatically do this relocate?

Comment: This answer has more votes than my chosen one. I think that the svnsync solution is better because the commits happen transparently on the server. No need to relocate. Great usability. The users just eventually find an weird error message when the mirror isn't full synced. Usually they just have to wait a couple of minutes and everything is fine.

Comment: Link to the chapter in svn redbook documenting write-through proxy setup: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy

Answer (score 7):

You should try [The SVK version control system](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage)

> [SVK](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage) is a decentralized version control system built with the robust Subversion filesystem. It supports repository mirroring, disconnected operation, history-sensitive merging, and integrates with other version control systems, as well as popular visual merge tools.

On this link there is text about [Using SVK to Synchronize SVN Repositories](http://lajavaloca.wordpress.com/2008/06/03/using-svk-to-synchronize-svn-repositories/)

Answer (score 2):

If one of the repositories is fully read only you can use 'svnsync' to keep it up to date with the master repository. This tool is often used in combination with the proxy support to create a master slave setup.

E.g. Apache does this to mirror their repository to different continents. The master repostitory is located in the US, but if I access the repository from the EU I get a local mirror that works just as well as the master server.

Answer (score 1):

The inotify-tools works well for me, details are mentioned on this website:

http://planet.admon.org/synchronize-subversion-repositories-with-inotify-tools/

Answer (score 1):

There is a commercial solution that provides true active-active replication (not master-slave) of Subversion repositories if you need performance and data safety beyond what svnsync provides called "Subversion MultiSite".

Disclaimer: I work for the company that makes this solution

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN Server's [Multisite Repository Replication](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) was designed for this case.

You can keep the master repository in your main office and setup multiple writeable slave repositories at the remote locations.

> This should work as transparently as possible for the developers.
>   Usability is a must.

- The replication between the slaves and the master is transparent and automatic,
- Each master and slave repository is a writable Subversion repository from the user's standpoint,
- Works out-of-the-box and can be configured in a couple of clicks via VisualSVN Server Manager MMC console.

[image: VisualSVNServerManagerConsoleMultisite]

Comment: The product looks nice. You just forgot to say that it costs a thousand dollars.

Comment: Also, both mirror and slave must Visual SVN server.