# Setting php development server with subversion

Tags: svn

I have a testing server for php applications. I decided to start using subversion which I installed and it works fine but I need some help with the following scenario. I want each developer to be able to checkout their own copy on that server, then test it by simply going to url and if everything seems fine then commit their changes. Then when all new features have been implemented the code would be pushed to production.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111436/how-can-i-get-the-svn-revision-number-in-php ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by synchronizing the repository on your Apache server with the other server. Have a look at the following thread: [How to synchronize two Subversion repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143130/how-to-synchronize-two-subversion-repositories)

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I edited my question, could you please review it.